# Truecrypt cannot build

Tags: c++, build, truecrypt

```
6>ComSetup.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/SAFESEH' specification
6>  Setup.vcxproj -> C:\Truecrypt\Source\Setup\Debug\TrueCryptSetup.exe
        ========== Rebuild All: 6 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the message after I build the Truecrypt source code for Windows on Visual Studio 2012. I succeeded but my file at `C:\Truecrypt\Source\Setup\Debug\TrueCryptSetup.exe` does not work.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning that you can ignore. The file seems to have been compiled successfully, but you need to put the relevant DLLs in the same folder as truecrypt.exe. These missing DLLs is probably what makes the program crash.

Comment: What if you try to run it in a debugger? Does it give you any meaningful error message?

Answer (score 0):

The code below is buggy, at least on my machine. Try commenting out the line marked //nj just to get going.

```
for (i = 0; headers[i] != 0; i++)
{
    if (HeaderResource[i] == NULL)
    {
        HeaderResource[i] = MapResource ("Header", headers[i], &size);
```

//nj            *(HeaderResource[i] + size - 1) = 0;
        }

.....
and

```
if (LanguageResource == NULL)
{
    DWORD size;
    LanguageResource = MapResource ("Xml", IDR_LANGUAGE, &size);
//nj    LanguageResource[size - 1] = 0;
}
```